# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: pos < flushedPos! while reading an image

Tags: java, image, png, base64

Hi I have this String str which encoded to Base64:
`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACYAAAAtCAYAAADC+hltAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0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`

Here is how I convert it to `byte[]`:

```
byte[] imageByte = Base64.decode(str);
```

and here is how I want to save it on my machine:

```
    BufferedImage image = null;
    String path = EVENT_FOLDER + name + "." + extension;

    try
    {
        image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte));
        ImageIO.write(image, extension, new File(path));
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: pos < flushedPos!
    at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.seek(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:768)
    at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.skipBytes(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:738)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:676)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1229)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1577)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
    at com.evappserver.util.ImageUploader.uploadEventImage(ImageUploader.java:38)
    at com.evappserver.logiclayer.NewEventLogic.createNewEvent(NewEventLogic.java:64)
    at com.evappserver.servlets.NewEventServlet.doGet(NewEventServlet.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Note:** here are some links to online converters: [link](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) [link](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create) [link](http://www.base64-image.de/)

What this error says? how do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting your original string?

Comment: I am converting it for this example from online converter from uploaded image to base64. U can Google it

Answer (score 1):

I bet the problem is that the tool you used is actually not converting the original file, but is encoding the image data itself. This means that the input isn't appropriate for `ImageIO`.

Comment: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/ worked for me. Note that you should *not* treat the decoded string as 'an image', it's a complete file.

Comment: @Jongware: That is what he does: he treats it as a complete file. So that is fine, at least if he did the encoding right.